# how to configure http request pipeling using wrk?

Tags: node.js, load-testing, lua

I am trying to load test nodejs helloworld, which is running on system 1 at http://10.20.10.10:5000 and I want to pipeline http requests from system 2. wrk takes a script as a parameter. I am wondering what should be in the script pipeline.lua? Just the url?

sample pipeline.lua script.

```
init = function(args)
   local r = {}
   r[1] = wrk.format(nil, "/?foo")
   r[2] = wrk.format(nil, "/?bar")
   r[3] = wrk.format(nil, "/?baz")

   req = table.concat(r)
end

request = function()
   return req
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Just change the URL.
You pipeline script should look something like-

```
init = function(args)
   local r = {}
   r[1] = wrk.format(nil, "url to test")
   r[2] = wrk.format(nil, "url to test")
   r[3] = wrk.format(nil, "url to test")

   req = table.concat(r)
end

request = function()
   return req
end
```

This will send three pipelined requests.